# Proximal Mapping of Composition with Linear Operator

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I've posted this question on math overflow but got no answer, so I think it might not be a research level question so I decided to post it here too.

Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix. It is well known that the proximal mapping $prox_{f \circ A}(x)$ can be evaluated efficiently by
$$
(I + \partial (f \circ A))^{-1}(x) = prox_{f \circ A}(x) = A^T prox_{f}(A x),
$$
as described here:

[Proximal mapping for composition of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147987/proximal-mapping-for-composition-of-functions)

I was wondering if this extends to a proximal mapping with a diagonal matrix $D$ as step size:
$$
(I + D \partial (f \circ A))^{-1}(x) = ?
$$
I'm asking if the above proximal operator is easily to evaluate, assuming that $(I + D \partial f)^{-1}$ is easy.

I have been trying quite a while to find some closed-form for the above, but it seems difficult. I do not want to use an iterative method like ADMM to evaluate the proximal mapping.

Comment: Maybe in the general case it is hard, but for a specific family of functions it is easier. Can you elaborate on the problem, or family of problems, you are trying to solve?

Comment: A family of functions I would be interested in are separable functions, i.e. $f : R^n \rightarrow R$, $f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$ where $f_i$ is a one-dimensional function. An example would be the $\ell_1$-norm.